# Type conversion for a String in an array throws "Unknown Source Error" in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, type-conversion

I am trying to parse a CSV file with java and get some id*s*.

I have passed the contents in a list and each list elements contains a line of information from the csv file which has the format user_id, poi_id, times_visited like this:

[image]

After passing all its contents I use .split(",") to break the contents inside each record in an array for easy access.

Now when I try to convert the poi_id from string to Integer with parseInt with this code:

```
    ArrayList<POI> poi_list = new ArrayList<POI>();
    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++) {
        String checking = lista.get(i);
        String[] checking_array = checking.split(",");
        System.out.println("checking_array's second element for list.get("+i+") is: "+checking_array[1]);
        int id = Integer.parseInt(checking_array[1]);
        POI item = new POI(id);
        poi_list.add(item);
    }
```

I get this error:

[image]
In text:

```
checking_array's second element for list.get(0) is:  149   
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
    149"
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
            at M.main(M.java:28)
```

Now when I check for the first element of the array (although it is not what I want), it is converted correctly and flows perfect with this code:

```
 ArrayList<POI> poi_list = new ArrayList<POI>();
        for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++) {
            String checking = lista.get(i);
            String[] checking_array = checking.split(",");
            System.out.println("checking_array's second element for list.get("+i+") is: "+checking_array[1]);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(checking_array[0]);
            POI item = new POI(id);
            poi_list.add(item);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

In text:

```
checking_array's second element for list.get(8458) is:  475
checking_array's second element for list.get(8459) is:  526
checking_array's second element for list.get(8460) is:  542
checking_array's second element for list.get(8461) is:  866
checking_array's second element for list.get(8462) is:  927
checking_array's second element for list.get(8463) is:  1055
checking_array's second element for list.get(8464) is:  1083
checking_array's second element for list.get(8465) is:  1318
checking_array's second element for list.get(8466) is:  1372
checking_array's second element for list.get(8467) is:  1501
checking_array's second element for list.get(8468) is:  1931
checking_array's second element for list.get(8469) is:  1942
```

It confuses me because it seems that the array is accessible and when I print it as a String everything is fine, but when I try specifically the second element, it cannot be converted to an Integer?

Comment: please post the stacktrace as text instead of as a screenshot. There may be special characters in the string.

Comment: Most likely your splitting results in strings that are not numbers. Try printing that string before parsing, ideally with some markers around it to clearly see what the string contains.

Comment: Since the second example prints out the numbers correctly, shouldn't it mean there are no special characters inside the string?

Comment: The error here is `NumberFormatException`. `Unknown Source` merely means that you don't have the debugging information available that allows the source file of the error to be reported.

Comment: @Efthimis_28 no way for us to know since you posted the output as a screenshot as well, I am not sure if normal whitespaces are a problem for integer parsing, but some other invisible unicode character certainly are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way your output is spaced, it looks like you might have a leading space character in there which could be causing the parsing trouble. Try this:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(checking_array[1].trim());
```

Comment: Yes, maybe my eyes should be more careful with the spacing in files. Thanks.

Comment: I find it annoying that the standard Java `parseInt` function doesn't ignore leading and trailing spaces by default. The equivalent in JavaScript is lenient that way.

Comment: 100% agree. After dealing with other more modern functions that deal with this kind of just blank space I expected parse to do the same, although my mind ran through that thought for 0.5 ms.